# formulario con bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo algunos problemas con un formulario en Bootstrap, ya que los input los coloca muy pequeños de su tamaño normal, estoy aprendiendo a usar la grid de Bootstrap pero no le he entendido muy bien, por eso solicito su ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
mi codigo es este

```
<form id="registrationForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="#">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Nombres</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Apellidos</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu CSS lo carga bien el único detalle que puedes tener es que estas colocando la clase `.col-lg-*` prueba cambiar esa clase por `.col-sm-*` este puede ser un problema en pantallas con una resolución pequeña.

La clase `col-sm-*` te puede ser funcional tanto como pantallas mayores a `996 px`, si el cambiar las clases no funciona puede que se deba a que al archivo de javascript de bootstrap este duplicado si usas un diseño dinámico.

- para ajustar en pantallas de dispositivos móviles pequeños se usa `col-xs-*`
- para tabletas es `col-sm-*`.
- para pantallas con una resolución superior o igual a `996 px` se usa `col-md-*`
- para pantallas de `1200 px` en adelante usa `col-lg-*`

Reemplazando las `*` por la numeración de `1 - 12`.
De igual manera aquí esta la documentacion de [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) en el apartado de grid system

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que te esté cargando correctamente el css de bootstrap.

Como puedes ver simplemente copiando tu código y cargando el css de bootstrap los controles se redimensionan bien:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="registrationForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="#">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Nombres</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Apellidos</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
  </form>
```